# Collapsible Bootstrap List Item for Task Queue

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to create an updating queue of tasks where each line on the queue displays relevant information about the task and allows the user to "check out" the task ( implying that they will work on it ) and then eventually have the option to remove the task (once the task is complete). So far, I have the following:
[Working example of bootstrap html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIbeu.png)

What I'm thinking about doing is adding a button to each line, or possibly making the entire line clickable, which will expand the line and provide users with a text entry option or a button to close the job. I've tried various options such as a panel or an accordion, but I haven't been able to get the formatting to work or the proper information to display.

Along with the formatting, the html page needs to be able to accept data for each request so that the SQL server can be updated on the status of the job. I'm using jinja2 to loop through tasks to display the list above but I'm not sure how to use jinja to pass the appropriate information to Flask/Python. i.e make sure that the POST request data corresponds to the correct queue entry.

I've inserted the code below. It may look a bit off because I actually used the "block" feature in jinja to extend a base template but combined them into one code snippet to be complete.

Any help or suggestions on better implementation methods would be greatly appreciated!

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale = 1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

        <title>Design Queue</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul class="list-group">
        {%for drequest in designRequests%}
        <li class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between list-group-item-action collapse" >
          <div class="p-2"><b>Request From:</b> {{drequest.requestor}}</div>
          <div class="p-2"><b>Project:</b> {{drequest.proj}}</div>
          <div class="p-2"><b>Description:</b>{{drequest.desc}}</div>
          <div class="p-2"><b>Due Date:</b> {{drequest.get_due_date()}}</div>
          {}
        </li>
        {%endfor%}
      </ul>
     </body>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
      <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"         integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use a button or make the entire line clickable, you can use a modal to display the data entry/modification interface.  You can update the information on the modal using data-bs attributes.  Use Jinja templating to set the data-bs attributes for each record.  Have the modal then have its own button to submit data and pass back the updated data (along with some record ID).   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: The modal component is really cool! I think that it should help me avoid having to implement a "collapse" and serve as a better user experience.

So are you suggesting pass some value to a data-bs attribute via jinja templating and then have the modal submit a separate form with the modal entries and some identifier for each instance in the queue? From there I assume you just use the identifier to correspond the modal entries to the respective object and update the SQL server.

That seems like a good plan, ill try it out.